# ANTLR4 force LL(1)

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4, ll-grammar

How do I force ANTLR4 to accept LL(1) grammars only?

As an academic exercise, we have to make an LL(1) grammar. However, ANTLR4 just accepts LL(*) grammars without warning that it's not LL(1). I understand that usually, LL(*) is preferable, but LL(1)-ness is a requirement for the exercise.

I could not find it as an option or argument, nor in the definitive antlr4 guide...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net) instead: by default, it expects LL(1) grammars.

Comment: It can do LL(k) also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. The entire point of ANTLR 4 is to remove traditional limitations like LL(1) from consideration during development and implementation of a new language.